# Python: Extracting the lower quantile from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, percentile

I have a dataframe column which is a set of number in descending order and I need to assign the lowest %10 to a new dataframe. But I couldn't find a way to extract the lowest %10. Thanks in advance.

First function I've tried is `percentile` function of numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df['Column']` #which has 2400 number

array1 = np.array(df['Column'])

np.percentile(array1,10)` #gave me the variable which is the %10 (just 1 variable) but I need the list of lowest %10
```

Second code I've tried is `cut` function of pandas

```
pd.qcut(df['Column'], q =10) # divides the dataframe to 10 equal piece. But I couldn't find a way to extract lowest %10
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, so that we can help you out?

Comment: Hi Itamar, how can I extract the highest %10 with using same code/function? I've tried to sort the list in descending order and run the same code but it gave me again the lowest %10 which is last 240 rows for 2400 rows column in descending order.

Comment: Simple, top 10% is above 0.9 quantile, so just replace `le` with `ge` in my code and replace 0.1 with 0.9

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, sorry. Cause while length of my data is 2337 the code gave me 240 for the lowest %10 and 446 for the highest #10. I think the problem is that I have a list of number between 1 to 100 and the number of numbers is 2337 which means I have some repeated numbers in my column. I just need to extract first and last %10 rows which should be 234 from the start and the end.

Comment: Your latest comment changes the question you asked. You state the you need the result's shape to be strictly 10% of the input, not just the highest/lowest 10% of values. Effectively, you're asking another, follow-up question.

Comment: I've edited again to answer your original question and the additional two that you added in comments. In the future, please try to ask your entire question up front, and not incrementally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is to get the rows that satisfy this condition, you can do this with simple slicing. Let's walk through it:

1. To get the 10% quantile threshold, use `df['Column'].quantile(0.1)`
2. To get the rows where this column is below (or equal) to this threshold, use `df['Column'].le(df['Column'].quantile(0.1))` (or equivalently, `df['Column'] <= df['Column'].quantile(0.1)`).
3. The previous expression gave a series with an index matching the df's index and values of `True`/`False` where the values match / don't match the condition. Such a series can be passed as index to the df to filter only the desired rows.

To sum it up, what you want is:

```
df_2 = df[df['Column'].le(df['Column'].quantile(0.1))]
```

EDITED: For the top 10%, similarly use

```
df_2 = df[df['Column'].ge(df['Column'].quantile(0.9))]
```

EDITED (again, as per comment by OP):

If you need to get an exact number (e.g. exactly 10% of your dataset, regardless of duplicate values), you can sort the dataframe by the relevant column and pick the top/bottom *n* values (where *n* might be, for example, df.shape[0]//10), like this:

```
df_2 = df.sort_values('Column').tail(df.shape[0]//10) # top 10%
df_2 = df.sort_values('Column').head(df.shape[0]//10) # bottom 10%
```

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted (with the little green "v") so others know it's closed.

Comment: Upvote for the well-explained and concise answer.  Nice work.